# How does one find the definition of a function in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I've been tasked with making changes to an Excel 2010 spreadsheet I know little about.  I was pretty good with Excel about a decade ago, but I'm not really sure how to look-up the definitions of particular formulas I see used in cells.

For instance, in one cell I see what I assume is a function call **`=CEMPRICE!$L$19`**, I assume this is a call to function `CEMPRICE` with the contents of cell `L19`.

Where do I find the definition of `CEMPRICE` and how it works?

Comment: That is not a function call, that is a call to the worksheet CEMPRICE (it would not be a valid statement otherwise).  Check if your workbook has any hidden worksheets.  If it was a function call, it would appear as `=CEMPRICE($L$19)` with parentheses.  A name followed by an exclamation mark is a sheet reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the example you give, CEMPRICE is a sheet reference, so you would have a sheet named "CEMPRICE" (look on the sheet tabs).

You can call up help to look at a built-in function definition, by hitting F1, or using the menu.

For User-defined functions (macros, UDFs) you'll have to go to the VBA editor, the easy way is hitting Alt-F11.

Answer (score -2):

In the help search bar in the upper-left corner of the Excel window, type CEMPRICE and see what MS says about the function.

Or google "excel function CEMPRICE". I did this, however, and it didn't return any relevant results, so this is either a custom function defined in the VBA/macros for this sheet, or it's not a function.

Comment: What's with the vote down?

Comment: @musci2myear it is a sheetname as was noted above by a couple people and someone probably thought the ! in the formula should make that obvious, but I agree the downvoter explaining would have been nice, especially since it would help others to understand